# How to dynamically select a range VBA

Tags: vba, range

My question is very similar to the following:

[Excel VBA code to select non empty cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967118/excel-vba-code-to-select-non-empty-cells/39967976#39967976)
However, I have some empty cells in between. In particular, I'm trying to define a range where the first row needs to be excluded, since it's a header. I also have to exclude the empty cells that follow. I was trying something like

```
Dim wb as workbook, ws as worksheet
Dim myrange as range

'Defined reference wb and ws
myrange=ws.range("B2",range("B2"),end(xldown))
```

But this only works if there are not empty cells in between. So, is there a fast and simple way to dynamically select a range that includes non-empty cells, excepted the header?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```vb
'Defined reference wb and ws
Set myrange = ws.range("B2", ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

Don't forget to use the `Set` keyword

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. Can you explain to me, please, how this works exactly? Why not xldown?

Comment: `xlDown` stops when it finds a blank cell.

Comment: `.End(xlDown)` is the same as pressing `Ctrl`+`Down Arrow`. `.End(xlUp)` is the same as pressing `Ctrl`+`Up Arrow`. In this code, you are essentially going to the last cell in column B and pressing `Ctrl`+`Up` and the you use the cell you end up with. Does this suffice?

Answer (score 2):

Try the next way, please:

```
Sub testDefineRange()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, myrange As Range

 Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here what you need
 lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 'Defined reference ws
 Set myrange = ws.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
 myrange.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please remove the `Select`-statement at the end or at least add a comment that this was added only to demonstrate the result.

Comment: @FunThomas: I kept it there for exactly the same reason. He can easily delete it, after having the confirmation that the code works as he needs. :)

Comment: Yes. Of course he *could* delete it. If you would mention why you put it there in the first place. And if you would mention that this code will work only with the `ActiveSheet` (else you will get a runtime error).

Comment: @FunThomas: `Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here what you need` should let him defining the sheet which he needs. I only tried to adapt **his code** in a way to make it working as he asked in his question. Otherwise, it could be easy to to be done in only one code line...

Comment: And if ws is set to any other sheet, it will fail. OP doesn't mention anything about using Activesheet. And code should **never** rely on ActiveSheet (or Selection). Of course it can be done with one line (although I think it's better to split it on 2 lines and save the last row into a variable), this has been asked (and answered) 100 times here on SO.

Comment: @FunThomas: I cannot get you, sorry... Do you want me to delete the answer? If yes, this will not be a problem! But he does use a declaration (`ws as worksheet`) and he did not define it. The easiest way of showing a test code, **when it is not clear what sheet does he have in mind**, is to refer the active sheet. I consider that I spent much more time to clarify something not important than I should. I wish you a good day!

Comment: I don't mind about if this answer stays or not. I wanted to point out the problem with the `Select`. BTW: Obviously the OP has defined `ws` somewhere, else he would have gotten a runtime error.

Comment: @FunThomas:  His code could not work, anyhow! It could not work without `Set`, with a coma instead of a dot  in `range("B2"),end(xldown)`. He only tried to show us a piece of code (not copied) and told us a story regarding what problem he faces. I only tried to use his code pattern and show a way to make it functional. And offer a solution to rapidly check if returns what he needs...

Comment: I give up. But that's a common feeling about contributing to SO these days anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this link to be very useful on MANY occasions.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Ways To Find The Last Row

```
Sub FindingLastRow()
'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Using SpecialCells Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Ways To Find The Last Column

```
Sub FindingLastColumn()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last column number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(7, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastColumn = sht.UsedRange.Columns(sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

'Using Table Range
  LastColumn = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastColumn = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Columns.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Right (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastColumn = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If it suits your case, I like to use CurrentRegion with Intersect to eliminate the title row.

```
with ws.range("b2")
   set myRange = intersect(.currentregion, .currentregion.offset(1,0))
end with
debug.print myRange.address
```